# Error in ArcPro's Fill Missing Values Tool using arcpy in Python

Tags: python, missing-data, arcgis, esri, arcpy

Fill Missing Values Tool runs perfectly fine in ArcPro, but when attempting to do the same in Python using arcpy module, it returns an error. The error message indicates a problem within the internal ArcGIS script (SSImpute.py). Can someone please provide guidance or any possible solutions to ensure that the Fill Missing Values Tool works correctly in Python?

**MY SCRIPT:**

```
arcpy.stpm.FillMissingValues(in_features = fc, fields_to_fill = "BlPCI", fill_method = "MEDIAN", conceptualization_of_spatial_relationships = "K_NEAREST_NEIGHBORS", number_of_spatial_neighbors = 4, append_to_input = "APPEND_TO_INPUT")
```

I tried doing the same thing (same in_feature, fields_to_fill, fill_method, conceptualization_of_spatial_relationships, number_of_spatial_neighbors, and append_to_input) in ArcPro, and it worked.

**ERROR MESSAGE:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\\NRE_5585\\SRD\\SRDFinalScripts\\A2I3PerCapInc.py", line 71, in \<module\>
arcpy.stpm.FillMissingValues(in_features=fc,
File "C:\\Program Files\\ArcGIS\\Pro\\Resources\\ArcPy\\arcpy\\stpm.py", line 1399, in FillMissingValues
raise e
File "C:\\Program Files\\ArcGIS\\Pro\\Resources\\ArcPy\\arcpy\\stpm.py", line 1396, in FillMissingValues
retval = convertArcObjectToPythonObject(gp.FillMissingValues_stpm(\*gp_fixargs((in_features, out_features, fields_to_fill, fill_method, conceptualization_of_spatial_relationships, distance_band, temporal_neighborhood, time_field, number_of_spatial_neighbors, location_id, related_table, related_location_id, weights_matrix_file, unique_id, null_value, out_table, append_to_input), True)))
File "C:\\Program Files\\ArcGIS\\Pro\\Resources\\ArcPy\\arcpy\\geoprocessing_base.py", line 520, in \<lambda\>
return lambda \*args: val(\*gp_fixargs(args, True))
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "\<string\>", line 5010, in execute
File "C:\\Program Files\\ArcGIS\\Pro\\Resources\\ArcToolbox\\Scripts\\SSImpute.py", line 251, in execute
values = ssi.imputeValues(fields)
File "C:\\Program Files\\ArcGIS\\Pro\\Resources\\ArcToolbox\\Scripts\\SSImpute.py", line 1153, in imputeValues
impValuesIds, extraField, countFilledByLoc, numNeighborUsed = self.\__expandImputedValues(value, impValuesIds)
File "C:\\Program Files\\ArcGIS\\Pro\\Resources\\ArcToolbox\\Scripts\\SSImpute.py", line 1231, in \__expandImputedValues
estimatedValues = NUM.zeros_like(values, dtype = NUM.int)
File "C:\\Users\\sabin\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages\\numpy_init_.py", line 305, in __getattr__
raise AttributeError(__former_attrs__\[attr\])
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'int'.
`np.int` was a deprecated alias for the builtin `int`. To avoid this error in existing code, use `int` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. When replacing `np.int`, you may wish to use e.g. `np.int64` or `np.int32` to specify the precision. If you wish to review your current use, check the release note link for additional information.
The aliases was originally deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance see the original release note at:
https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations

Failed to execute (FillMissingValues).
Process finished with exit code 1\`
```

Comment: I think the source of your issues is your Python environment. Looks like there is an issue with the version of `numpy`. How do you execute your script? Does your script adds some site packages? Or do you have the `PATH` variable set?